# Why we can't use AHB in the Cortex M0 MCU?

Tags: arm, bus, amba

I found coretex M0 MCU module's bus interface has not HBUSREQ and HGRANT, and HRESP when i trying to implement with AHB Bus.

Is there any way to use AHB not AHB_lite. I can't use multi-layer interconnect system. only I can use AHB.

Comment: You question is not clear without the context. Why can't you simply add those signals?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev because cortex m0 does not support AHB.

Answer (score 2):

Which interconnect are you using? You should find that a multi-layer AHB can be driven from AHB-Lite, either with some tie-offs, or using a bridge.
As to why, it is to avoid having extra logic in the core which isn't needed for the majority of use-cases. Adding the logic to support arbitration is no less efficient when it is external.